# Centos Apache installed in VMWare Workstation

Tags: apache-http-server, vmware-workstation

I have installed a Windows 7 and a CentOS on VMWare Workstation.

On CentOS, I have installed `Apache Server`, but I can't log in to the web-server from the Windows 7 client.

Both CentOS and Windows 7 can 'ping' each other though.

Any idea where the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I did a clean install of CentOS, I usually just clone from a template, but I believe that iptables will block port 80 by default. Either add an exception for that port or disable your firewall (not recommended if this is a public box).

Comment: TY. It works now